# Symmetrize from +X to -X

Tags: mesh, sculpting, mirror, axis

I'm using Blender 2.8 and want to symmetrize my sculpted model.
I've tried Modeling -> Mesh -> Symmetrize but this only offers to symmetrize from -X to +X. How can I symmetrize from +X to -X instead? I can't simply cut my model in half and use a Mirror Modifier due to the nature of the sculpted mesh (no clean line down the middle).

Comment: Once you've symmetrized, you have all the symmetrize options in the block on the bottom left of the 3D View, and you can choose +X to -X.

Comment: @moonboots This should actually be the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've symmetrized, you have all the symmetrize options in the *Operator* box on the bottom left of the 3D View, and you can choose +X to -X.

Comment: I would be curious to know why I've been downvoted

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't find a +X to -X Symmetrize function either, but a trivial solution would be to simply mirror the object before invoking Symmetrize...

Comment: I thought that mirroring with the mirror modifier would cause the mirrored faces to be present alongside the original faces for that half... but it seems that the original faces were replaced.

Comment: No, I didn't mean the mirror *modifier.* There is a Mirror *operation* in the same menu as the Symmetrize function. Alternatively, just scale the mesh along X by -1 .